# Vaadin - implement dom2image as component

Tags: javascript, java, vaadin

I have spent many hours integrating javascript libraries in Vaadin and I feel like I got stuck.

So I decided to ask this question exemplarily for dom-to-image to export an element from the dom tree to an image.

What I did:

- Created a class that extends Component
- Added NpmPackage, (JsModule or JavaScript) and the Tag annotation
- Created a function appendImg that accepts a component that I can use to get the referencing dom element (here a LMap from https://github.com/xdev-software/vaadin-maps-leaflet-flow) as done by `map.clientComponentJsAccessor()`.

What happens:

- The NPM package is downloaded
- No errors are shown neither in the console in my IDE nor in the browser
- The System out is printed
- That's it

When I remove the JS call to the entire `domtoimage()` function both alerts are shown in the browser. So I am pretty sure that the call causes the malfunction.

My question is now: How to proceed here? I don't get any errors and I have no clue on where to start fixing the call to `domtoimage()`. Am I doing sth essentially wrong? Hope you can help me out.

```
@NpmPackage(value = "dom-to-image", version = "2.6.0")
//@JsModule("dom-to-image")
@JavaScript("dom-to-image/dist/dom-to-image.min.js")
@Tag("dom-to-image")
public class Dom2Image extends Component {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
    public void appendImg(LMap map) {
        System.out.println("Printing...");
        getElement().executeJs("(function () {"
        + "alert('0');"
        + "domtoimage.toPng($0)"
        + "    .then(function (dataUrl) {"
        + "        console.log('exporting...');"
        + "        var img = new Image();"
        + "        img.src = dataUrl;"
        + "        document.body.appendChild(img);"
        + "    })"
        + "    .catch(function (error) {"
        + "        console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);"
        + "    })"
        + "alert('1');"
        + "})();", map.clientComponentJsAccessor());
    }
}
```

Comment: For a basic one-liner like this, shouldn't there be a `;` before the last `alert`?

Comment: You are right, I added the ";" and the first alert is shown. Unfortunately the following two lines aren't and I still don't get any error response.